# Django: Pass UserID to settings.py

Tags: django, froala

I need to pass the UserID to settings.py because of this line:

```html
FROALA_UPLOAD_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/froala_editor/', instance.user.id)
```

Comment: Later I have to add more variables in settings.py f.ex. PayPal API Key and Stripe API Key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with settings override function

[Custom default settings¶](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/)